# AVR: Serial communication gives strange characters

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, serial, embedded

I am having some serious problems trying to get the serial monitor to output the correct characters. I have looked over a lot of the posts with similar problems, but nothing seems to solve it.

I am an absolute rookie when it comes to this stuff, and we are working with embedded systems for a university course and the teacher isn't at much help.

I am simply trying to print the character "a" to the serial monitor, but all I get is these wonky characters that can be seen in the picture.

I attached the code and the picture, in hopes that someone more knowledgable in the area can pinpoint me in the right direction!

**Basic Info:**

Programming through a Arduino nano

programmer: arduino

baud rate: 56700

chip: atmega328p

```
#define  F_CPU 1000000UL

#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "usart.h"

int main(void) {

    uart_init(); // open the communication to the microcontroller
    io_redirect(); // redirect input and output to the communication

    while(1) {

        _delay_ms(1000);

        printf("a");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The usart.c and usart.h files are provided by the university. I can compile and flash to the chip no problems, just getting strange characters as output.

[image: The serial monitor output]

Every value of the baud rate under 57600 gives me this this response from avrdude.

[image]

There is one exception when I try to use 9600, I get the response:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempts 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempts 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempts 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
...
```

As I am totally new to this, I have no idea what it means, and google didn't help a lot. The only baud rate I can even flash to the chip, is at 57600.

Here you can see the uart_init function:

```
void uart_init(void) {

    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;

    #if USE_2X
    UCSR0A |= _BV(U2X0);
    #else
    UCSR0A &= ~(_BV(U2X0));
    #endif

    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(UCSZ00); /* 8-bit data */
    UCSR0B = _BV(RXEN0) | _BV(TXEN0);   /* Enable RX and TX */

}
```

Comment: It looks like something is happening. Double check the baud rate at each end, and the claimed cpu clock rate, which may be used in a rate divider calculation. Both ends have to agree exactly on speed.

Comment: Almost the same problem so if not already read, please check this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/269658/serial-output-returns-wrong-ascii/269670#269670

Comment: Try with lower baud rates too, 1200 is a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the responds guys! I have tried with lower baud rates, but then avrdude says the programmer wont respond. It only flashes to the chip if I use 56700 and up. I also did read that post, men to be frank, I had no idea what was going on.

Comment: This 56700 is the baud of the avrdude? Can you share the code of the uart init function?

Comment: That is the baud of the avrdude, yes. I edited my original post to include the code from the init function, because the formatting is weird in the comments :)

Comment: Do you know on what BAUD rate is set in this `uart_init` by `UBRR0H/L` registers? So what isupposed to be the BAUD rate of the Atmeg328p's UART BAUD rate?

Comment: I dont know if this is what you were asking for? `#ifndef BAUD
#define BAUD 9600
#endif`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about this line here;

```
#define  F_CPU 1000000UL
```

As far as i know arduino nano has 16Mhz onboard external oscillator and if you not changed default fuse settings it will work on 16Mhz.

Also try to make it working on lower baud values like 9600. And check your uart.h, make sure it has rigth UBBR value.

[image]

Comment: Read the question carefully. The OP uses an Arduino Nano to program an Atmega328p. The code runs on the Atmega328p.

Comment: I agree with this, Arduino nano or not, they dont use that clock speed

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response guys! Regarding the defined clock speed, I am not sure about it at all, but it was the template code provided by our teacher, and the other students (using windows) dont seem to have this problem. I tried it on my friends Mac the other day, and he has the same problem, but the same code works when done on windows. I tried removing the line, but still got the same problem. I also tried lowering the baud rate, but then avrdude says that the programmer wount respond.

Comment: If you are using internal RC oscillator take a look at these link

Comment: http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/internal-rc-oscillator-uart